# Why does downloading additional subtitles using the XBMC Subtitles add-on cause the subtitles not to work anymore? (XBMC/Raspbmc)

Tags: raspbmc, video, kodi, subtitles, xbmc-subtitles

Occasionally when I play a video that already has subtitles, I find that they're out of sync and so I search for and download subtitles using the [XBMC Subtitles add-on](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on%3aXBMC_Subtitles). However when I do, I find that the subtitles won't work at all after that (i.e. even though there are subtitles on disk, they aren't being displayed with the video), even if I try toggling them using the <kbd>t</kbd> keyboard shortcut. I usually find that I have to stop the video and then resume it from its last position from the file explorer. Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, I'm a doofus. Turns out it had nothing to do with the add-on at all -- I was playing around with the permissions of my external hard drive (which is where all my media is stored), and I accidentally set the permissions to `-w` for the "others" class, which is, I presume, what the user that runs the XBMC subtitles belongs to, and so it could no longer write to the video directories. My bad.